# Adding ArcGIS Pro Query Layer?

Tags: sql-server, arcgis-pro, query-layer, query-table

I am attempting to add a query layer to ArcGIS Pro 2.1.2 via SQL Server. 
The table consists of Ticket_ID, Latitude, Longitude. The query layer works if I only add the top 1000 rows. However, when I attempt to add all 79,592 rows, I keep returning the error: Failed to load data. Error: Failed to retrieve a page of rows.

Does ArcGIS Pro have a limit on query layer rows?

Comment: Is the TicketID field unique? Note that a Query Layer has a geometry column, so you're attempting a Query *Table*. I regularly work with 10m-40m row tables, so no there isn't a limit.

Comment: No, the TicketID field has duplicate values. Is this what is causing it to fail?

Comment: The duplicate ticketID values were the issue. Thank you.

Comment: Are your parameters defined appropriately? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/query-layers/define-parameters-in-a-query-layer.htm